# modrewrite for css / jss minified

Tags: javascript, css, mod-rewrite, minify

I have a web site hosted in a CentOS 5-Plesk-Apache server. I have recently added a second site to the server for serve dynamic content. I have established rewrite rules for images (static content) that works pretty well. The module rewrites the URI in the static server to pointing to the the original file.

The problem is that the first site has the minify (http://code.google.com/p/minify/) script installed but i cannot realize how to write a modwrite rule that works, so if I have:

...

< style src='http://www.mystaticserver.com/min/f=style.css' >

...

somewhere, this becomes in the file with this URL

http://www.myserver.com/min/f=style.css

Any ideas? Thank you in advance

PS: I asked this question in serverfault but i don't get any answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thaks to the guys at serverfault.com... This is the answer:

https://serverfault.com/questions/64223/modrewrite-for-css-jss-minified/65843#65843

Answer (score 0):

What are the redirect rules you are trying to use in the .htaccess file?

If you are sending the request to a different server, are you using redirectmatch?

Also, if you are including a query string you may need to apply the option [QSA] to the end to the rule to include it.